# PhoneGap : How to upload APK files on Google Play Store

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I have small android app. I made APK file from phonegap.com.

Now I tried to upload that APK file on Google Play Store..But it shows error:

```
Upload failed

You need to use a different package name because "com.phonegap.www" already exists in Google Play.
```

I am not getting the problem that where is com.phonegap.www package resides...I dont have this package structure in my application..www package is in asset folder.

Please give me some feasible solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is your package name? On phonegap build website click on your app, go to Settings tab, scroll down to Configuration and check what your package name is. Set it to something like com.yourCompanyName.yourAppName and rebuild your app.

If you're building through Eclipse set your package name in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: The Configuration tab no longer shows up in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not have any experience with Eclipse, I was able to resolve the same problem by generating a "Signed Release" APK in Android Studio (a "build" variant of the APK, not a "debuggable" one, as per http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.phonegap/69299).  As far as I can tell, the text in the AndroidManifest there isn't any different from what I had, but generating the build variant did work.  Also, trying to upload a debuggable version produces the following error fyi:  `You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play.`

Just to document my experience trying to troubleshoot the problem:  prior to turning to Android studio, I tried a number of times to resolve via the Cordova command line tools and PhoneGap Build.  I confirmed the package name was not  `com.phonegap.www` in `config.xml`, `AndroidManifest.xml`, and others (checking to make sure that text wasn't located anywhere in my project - it wasn't).  In case that package name was included in some cached version of the project, I removed, re-added and rebuilt the Android platform a number of times, trying different tweaks each time; using these updated builds at PhoneGap Build did not produce APKs that would be accepted at Google Play.  I also deleted the PhoneGap Build project and recreated, to ensure that I had not accidentally entered the problematic package name there somewhere - I hadn't.  Additionally, note that as of Apr. 2016, I do not have an option for "Configuration" for my projects at PhoneGap Build, so changing the package name there was not an option.

I haven't tried other options than what I've noted above, fyi, so can't speak to whether this is the quickest or most efficient way to get around this problem.  Am curious how to avoid it to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. You have to open your config.xml file and change the widget id at the top, both the second and third parts of it.

For example, com.phonegap.helloworld needs to change to com.mycompany.myappname. You cannot just change the last part, as that will not work in my experience.